# How to get timeout tuples in ShellBolt

Tags: apache-storm

I'm using ShellBolt (python multilang) in my storm cluster, and I often get subprocess heartbeat timeout Exceptions. I' like to find out the reason, so I want to know which tuples cause timeout issue.